# How do I add a line of text to the middle of a file using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, grep

I'm trying to add a line of text to the middle of a text file in a bash script.  Specifically I'm trying add a nameserver to my /etc/resolv.conf file.  As it stands, resolv.conf looks like this:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
domain dhcp.example.com
search dhcp.example.com
nameserver 10.0.0.1
nameserver 10.0.0.2
nameserver 10.0.0.3
```

My goal is to add `nameserver 127.0.0.1` above all other nameserver lines, but below any text above that.  In the end I want to my resolve.conf file to look like this:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
domain dhcp.example.com
search dhcp.example.com
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 10.0.0.1
nameserver 10.0.0.2
nameserver 10.0.0.3
```

How is this possible via a bash script?  Is this something sed or awk can do?  Or would creative greping to recreate the file be my best move?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here is a solution using sed:

```
$ sed -n 'H;${x;s/^\n//;s/nameserver .*$/nameserver 127.0.0.1\n&/;p;}' resolv.conf

# Generated by NetworkManager
domain dhcp.example.com
search dhcp.example.com
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 10.0.0.1
nameserver 10.0.0.2
nameserver 10.0.0.3
```

How it works: first, suppress the output of sed with the `-n` flag. Then, for each line, we append the line to the hold space, separating them with newlines:

```
H
```

When we come to the end of the file (addressed by `$`) we move the content of the hold space to the pattern space:

```
x
```

If the first line in pattern space is blank we replace it with nothing.

```
s/^\n//
```

Then we replace the first line starting with `nameserver` by a line containing `nameserver 127.0.0.1`, a new line (Your version of `sed` may not support `\n`, in which case replace the `n` with a literal newline) and the original line (represented by `&`):

```
s/nameserver .*$/nameserver 127.0.0.1\n&/
```

Now we just need to print the results:

```
p
```

Comment: This is great.  Only thing weird is it adds a blank line at the top of the new file.  Not a big deal, but it's causing an OCD moment.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right! The command `sed -n 'H;${x;s/^\n//;s/nameserver .*\n/nameserver 127.0.0.1\n&/;p;}' resolv.conf`, however, solves this problem. I added `s/^\n//` to the command so it will remove the newline at the beginning of the content of pattern space.

Comment: When running this same script on another machine with only one nameserver line it's not inserting anything.

Comment: Probably because there is no newline at the end of the line. It is easy to solve, too: `sed -n 'H;${x;s/^\n//;s/nameserver .*$/nameserver 127.0.0.1\n&/;p;}' resolv.conf` Now we replace from the first nameserver until the end of the file - I replaced the `\n` in `/nameserver .*\n/` by the marker of end of line `$`. Again, not that the `\n` in `/nameserver 127.0.0.1\n&/` may have to be replaced by a `\` followed by an actual newline in some sed versions.

Comment: Could this answer cause a problem due to the hold space if the file were massive and couldn't fit in memory?

Comment: I was inspired by your answer to help sleske : http://serverfault.com/a/745968/329412

Answer (score 37):

Assuming you want to insert immediately after the `search` line, this is much simpler:

```
sed -ie '/^search/a nameserver 127.0.0.1' filename
```

- `-i` : edit file in place
- `-e` : allows the execution of a script/commands inside sed expression
- `a mynewtext` : command that tells sed to insert the text mynewtext after matched pattern

Comment: That's the thing... that search line may or may not be there.  The nameserver lines should always be there, and I want the new line inserted immediately before them regardless of the rest of the contents of the file.

Comment: @PHLAK, the solution offered by Jim is good. I would modify it, though. Simply add a _special comment_ to mark the line where new stuff is supposed to be entered. E.g. a line like `#<<INSERT>>` or something. Then, instead of `/^search/` you can look for `/^#<<INSERT>>$/`, making it far more unlikely to match the wrong line.

Comment: How would you modify this (if possible) to use a single line from another file (assume that this file has only one line), instead of `nameserver 127.0.0.1`?

Comment: @Pom12 what do you mean by `-e : allows the execution of a script/commands inside sed expression`. Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe the `-e` flag does nothing. AFAIK it's used to specify multiple different sed commands and that's it. This is just 1

Answer (score 11):

`awk '/^nameserver/ && !modif { printf("INSERT\n"); modif=1 } {print}'`

Comment: Great `awk` solution, maybe the only one that does not copy the entire file to memory...

Comment: @MestreLion how do you figure? It reads every line, doesn't it? (I also like this solution)

Comment: @DanielKaplan: it does read and print every line, but _one at a time_, so the memory footprint does not depend on file size. Other solutions might accumulate until/if/after the insertion point is found, which is not desirable for arbitrarily large files.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like:

```
sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/nameserver/nameserver 127.0.0.1\nnameserver/' /etc/resolv.conf
```

(similar to this: [sed: Find pattern over two lines, not replace after that pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577057/sed-find-pattern-over-two-lines-not-replace-after-that-pattern/1582743#1582743))

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Perl solution:

`perl -lne 'if (not $f and /^nameserver/){ print "nameserver 127.0.0.1"; $f=1 }; print' resolv.conf`

- `-n` loop around every line of the input file, do not automatically print every line
- `-l` removes newlines before processing, and adds them back in afterwards
- `-e` execute the perl code

`$f` is used as a flag to indicate that the nameserver string has already been found

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
 sed -e '/nameserver/{x;/./b;x;h;i\nameserver 127.0.0.1' -e '}' resolv.conf
```

Or GNU sed:

```
sed -e '0,/nameserver/{//i\nameserver 127.0.0.1' -e '}' resolv.conf
```