# Bash: Inserting a line in a file at a specific location

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a script that will require me to add lines in a specific part of a config file. For example

Before:

```
ServerActors=IpServer.UdpServerUplink MasterServerAddress=unreal.epicgames.com MasterServerPort=27900
ServerActors=IpServer.UdpServerUplink MasterServerAddress=master0.gamespy.com MasterServerPort=27900
ServerActors=IpServer.UdpServerUplink MasterServerAddress=master.mplayer.com MasterServerPort=27900
ServerActors=UWeb.WebServer
```

After:

```
ServerActors=IpServer.UdpServerUplink MasterServerAddress=unreal.epicgames.com MasterServerPort=27900
ServerActors=IpServer.UdpServerUplink MasterServerAddress=master0.gamespy.com MasterServerPort=27900
ServerActors=IpServer.UdpServerUplink MasterServerAddress=master.mplayer.com MasterServerPort=27900
ServerActors=IpServer.UdpServerUplink MasterServerAddress=master.qtracker.com MasterServerPort=27900
ServerActors=UWeb.WebServer
```

As you can see there is a new line added. How can my bash script insert the line? I'm guessing I will need to use sed.

Comment: There are multiple ways and languages to do so, probably `awk` and `sed` being the best ones. Should you indicate the logic in these lines addition, so we can help solving it.

Comment: It's hard to infer a rule from one complicated case. Do you want to insert `ServerActors=IpServer.UdpServerUplink MasterServerAddress=master.qtracker.com MasterServerPort=27900` above every mention of `WebServer`? Or follow every `mplayer` line with a corresponding `qtracker` line, or what?

Comment: I think I found an answer. Not sure if there is a better way. But I have simply put in sed replace mplayer line with mplayer line *newline* qtracker line 

`sed -i 's/ServerActors=IpServer.UdpServerUplink MasterServerAddress=master.mplayer.com MasterServerPort=27900/ServerActors=IpServer.UdpServerUplink MasterServerAddress=master.mplayer.com MasterServerPort=27900\nServerActors=IpServer.UdpServerUplink MasterServerAddress=master.qtracker.com MasterServerPort=27900/g' /tmp/test`

Its a little long but it seems to work.

Comment: or to simplyfy 
`sed -i 's/line3/line3\nline5/g' /tmp/test`

Comment: @dgibbs,that's usually how I do - replace string before/after I want to insert keeping original in there and adding the new thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a line of text to the middle of a file using bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739258/how-do-i-add-a-line-of-text-to-the-middle-of-a-file-using-bash)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

If you want to add a line after a specific string match:

```
$ awk '/master.mplayer.com/ { print; print "new line"; next }1' foo.input
ServerActors=IpServer.UdpServerUplink MasterServerAddress=unreal.epicgames.com MasterServerPort=27900
ServerActors=IpServer.UdpServerUplink MasterServerAddress=master0.gamespy.com MasterServerPort=27900
ServerActors=IpServer.UdpServerUplink MasterServerAddress=master.mplayer.com MasterServerPort=27900
new line
ServerActors=UWeb.WebServer
```

Comment: I wonder why this didn't get more up votes, it's a way more dynamic way of handling the solution than explicitly knowing the line number your search text is on. +1 from me

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted one because it will reliably persist even if something else interacts with the file in question. e.g. I was using this on a Docker build of an nginx container and if someone were to add some config to it elsewhere, the accepted answer would break the build. This will not.

Comment: Why doesn't piping this back into the same file work? `awk ... foo.input > foo.input` just empties that file

Comment: @AndyRay Because shell redirection happens before any commands are run, which means the file is truncated immediately. See also [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/8418). The only way around this is using a temporary file, which for example `sed -i` does transparently. There's also `sponge` from `moreutils` which solves this problem.

Comment: It shows the expected output, but how to add that output to the file? File is unchanged

Comment: @SyedAsadAli See my comment above your question.

Comment: Is it possible to match a regular expression? I try to do it with [:space:] but it seems to not work. EDIT Ok it works

Comment: What's up with that `1` after `}` in `awk '/master.mplayer.com/ { print; print "new line"; next }1' foo.input`? EDIT: from @pieman72 's comment: If anyone else is confused, the 7 in this example can be any value that evaluates true. This is so that Awk knows to print every line. If there were no value there, then only the matched line (#5 in this case) would generate output ("new line text" in this case).

Answer (score 37):

You can use something like this:

Note that the command must be entered over multiple lines because sed does not allow coding a newline with "\n" or the Ctrl-V/Ctrl-M key combination like some tools.  The backslash says "Ignore my hitting the return key, I'm not done with my command yet".

```
sed -i.bak '4i\
This is the new line\
' filename
```

This should do the trick (It will insert it between line 3 and 4).

If you want to put this command itself into a shell script, you have to escape the backslashes so they don't get eaten by bash and fail to get passed to sed.  Inside a script, the command becomes:

```
sed -i.bak '4i\\
This is the new line\\
' filename
```

Comment: I see so you are specifying the line number

Comment: Yes, that way you can point precisely to where you want the line to be added.

Comment: another sed option similar to above would be sed '3a\ This is the new line' file

Comment: @MPrazz but here 4 is hardcoded ..?  I need a variable. Pls help.

Comment: what is .bak stands for ?

Comment: `.bak` means you want to create a backup with extension `".bak".` You could use `.foo` if you like and then the original file will be saved with name `filename.foo`

Answer (score 18):

```
awk 'NR==5{print "new line text"}7' file
```

Comment: sorry, for what is `7` here? ( `..."}7` )

Comment: @setevoy it will apply the default action of awk: print.

Comment: @Kent Must be a [bond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Bond) lover. But like you said bond should use `007` if he using `awk` so `+1`. `;)`!

Comment: If anyone else is confused, the `7` in this example can be any value that evaluates true. This is so that Awk knows to print every line. If there were no value there, then only the matched line (#5 in this case) would generate output ("new line text" in this case).

Answer (score 5):

You can add it with `sed` in your file `filename` after a certain string `pattern` match with:

```
sed '/pattern/a some text here' filename
```

in your example

```
sed '/master.mplayer.com/a \  new line' filename
```

(The backslash masks the first space in the new line, so you can add more spaces at the start)

source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121166/20661

Comment: If you want alter file inserting the new line, you can add "-i" parameter to sed command. This will change file with" new line".

sed -i '/master.mplayer.com/a \  new line' filename

Answer (score 0):

if you are using sed you need to use -i option to save content in original file otherwise it will only print output in terminal

```
sed -i '/pattern/a \some text here' filename
```