# Write to specific line in bash or python

Tags: python, apache, bash, .htaccess

I'm trying to make it easier for me to keep my url shortener less spammy. When I have to go in through ssh and keep adding another line to my .htaccess it gets really tedious and annoying really fast. So I was wondering if there was a way to add a line of text easily and that could be put in a script

Example:

```
<Directives here>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from 255.255.255.255
Deny from 0.0.0.0
Deny from 1.2.3.4
<Other Directives here as well as ending Directive>
```

Now lets say for giggles I wanted to add 127.0.0.1 and 192.168.0.1 to this, but since I can't directly echo where I want it, how would I go about this. Bash or Python answers accepted

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272379/bash-inserting-a-line-in-a-file-at-a-specific-location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a combination of `head`, `echo` and `tail`, you can create a temporary file with the required lines, and then `mv` or `cp` over the original file.

Add `Deny from 127.0.0.1` to your example .htaccess:

```
(head -n -1 .htaccess
 echo 'Deny from 127.0.0.1'
 tail -n 1 .htaccess) > .htaccess.tmp
mv -b .htaccess.tmp .htaccess

# cat .htaccess
<Directives here>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from 255.255.255.255
Deny from 0.0.0.0
Deny from 1.2.3.4
Deny from 127.0.0.1
<Other Directives here as well as ending Directive>
```

`head -n -1`: get all original lines except the last, `echo` the new line, `tail -n 1`: get last original line. `() >` writes everything to temporary file. `mv -b` overwrites the original, saving a backup.

This solution of course assumes you know how many lines from the end of file you want to add your new content.

Answer (score 0):

sed is probably the easiest to use and almost everywhere available. The following will insert a line before the last one:

`sed -e '$i Deny from 192.168.0.1' .htaccess`

This works assuming you want to insert before the last line. Having read your question a second time I noticed you wrote "<Other **Directives** here...>". Although this is a bit of a hidden hint, I assume you want to insert a line to the first section into content like this:

```
<Directive_1>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from 255.255.255.255
Deny from 0.0.0.0
Deny from 1.2.3.4
</Directive_1>
...
<Directive_n>
...
</Directive_n>
```

The following sed command will insert a line just before the closing tag of the first section:

`sed -e '/^<\/Directive_1>$/i Deny from 192.168.0.1' .htaccess`

Comment: By adding the `-i` option, the existing `.htaccess` file can be changed in place: `sed -i -e '$i Deny from 192.168.0.1' .htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way, in sh/ksh/bash:
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/contextual