# Overwrite part of a large file in Python

Tags: python, io, bittorrent

I am writing a bit torrent client and allocate space on hard drive for each file I have to download.

File can be huge and I want to overwrite some piece of it without deleting all content.

I read some other answers, but they suggest creating a temporary space and then copying changes back. That would be too heavy process.

I am sure there must be some utility.

Comment: It is very difficult to modify in place binary files. I think this is what you are trying to do. For example, if you are downloading a mp3 file or a movie, it is very difficult - almost impossible - to overwrite a specific part of the file, without corrupting the rest of it. If you are downloading a plain text file, then this is a bit simpler - however, it is more efficient to use an intermediary temporary file.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Exactly.

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: I need to write file piece by piece and I don't want to have whole file content on RAM. I cant find utility to do it without overwriting file with same content each time every 32 kb piece gets downloaded. I can preallocate enough space.

Comment: And pieces are not downloaded in order.

Comment: Are you creating a streaming client? This is the only scenario where the order of chunks is important.

Comment: I am writing bittorrent client.

Comment: Most languages should provide one of the following (since that's what provided by posix standards): seek+write buffer of a given length, write with offset + length, memory-map a region of that file, write to mapping. You'll have to make sure that the file is opened for writing, not for append. All of those should write just the data without clobbering anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are talking about a download file, you should consider the storage of downloaded data in a temporary file(chunks). Refer : [streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/how-to-download-large-file-in-python-with-requests-py) & [text-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125703/how-do-i-modify-a-text-file-in-python)

If I read you question (without python), I would say you could use OS specific commands to overwrite parts of a file.

For example in Linux, use `sed` or `awk`.
Refer : [Inserting-a-line-in-a-file-at-a-specific-location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272379/bash-inserting-a-line-in-a-file-at-a-specific-location)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, using OS (Linux) specific system call:

```
fd = os.open(path, os.O_WRONLY)
os.lseek(fd, offset, os.SEEK_SET)
os.write(fd, piece)
os.close(fd)
```

This did overwrite file without nullifying it.
But when had:

```
with open(path, 'wb') as file:
    file.seek(offset)
    file.write(piece)
```

It was deleting all other content.

Program is not portable this way but I don't need it to be.

Comment: It was deleting all other content?