# Insert text in the middle of a text file after the first occurence of a search string using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am wondering if it is possible to insert some text in the middle of a text file after the first occurrence of a search string using GNU sed.

So for example, if the search string is "Hello",  I would like to insert a string right after the first occurrence of "Hello" on a new line

```
Hello John, How are you?
....
....
....
Hello Mary, How are you doing?
```

The string would be entered right after "Hello John, How are you?" on a new line

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a line of text to the middle of a file using bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739258/how-do-i-add-a-line-of-text-to-the-middle-of-a-file-using-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say:

```
sed '/Hello/{s/.*/&\nSomething on the next line/;:a;n;ba}' filename
```

in order to insert a line after the first occurrence of the desired string, e.g. `Hello` as in your question.

For your sample data, it'd produce:

```
Hello John, How are you?
Something on the next line
....
....
....
Hello Mary, How are you doing?
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed '/Hello John, How are you?/s/$/\nsome string\n/' file
Hello John, How are you?
some string

....
....
....
Hello Mary, How are you doing?
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I picked devnull's answer because it is more general.

Comment: Not sure what is general in mine or his answer, both are producing same output. But for better portable solutions always consider awk over sed.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk '/Hello/ && !f {print $0 "\nNew line";f=1;next}1' file
Hello John, How are you?
New line
....
....
....
Hello Mary, How are you doing?
```

This search for sting `Hello` and if flag `f` is not true (default at start)
If this is true, print the line, print extra text, set flag `f` to true, skip to next line.
Next time `Hello` is found flag `f` is true and nothing extra will be done.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/Hello/ a/
Your message with /
New line' YourFile
```

`a/` for append (after) your pattern to find, `i/` for instert (before)