# Linux: How to insert a line at a specific line number in a file?

Tags: linux, insert

I'd like to add a specific line to a file in a specific line number (second) without over-writing the data which is already there.

I've tried this:

```
sed -i '2i - jstat' FILE
```

But this just over-writes the second line with "- jstat".

Instead, I want to add a new second line and push the next line to be number 3.
Let's say the file looks like that:

```
[root@puppet roles]# head -5 !$
head -5 buncher.yaml
classes:
  - workspace
  - fstab
  - role_specific
```

I'd like to add a new module on the second line and I want the "workspace" module to become the third line.

More than that, I'd like the new line to start with a tab size of 2 chars and then "- jstat" as in: "TabTab - jstat", how can it be done?

Comment: try looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739258/how-do-i-add-a-line-of-text-to-the-middle-of-a-file-using-bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to insert a line after before line number `x`, you can use the below `sed` command:

```
sed 'x i\LINE_TO_ADD' filename > temp_file
mv temp_file filename
```

Here is the example for adding `<TAB><TAB>Hello How are you!` to the `tempfile` whose content are:

```
123
234
345
```

To add before line number 2 I wrote the following `sed` command:

```
sed '2 i\\t\tHello How are you!' tempfile > temp_file
mv temp_file tempfile
```

Final content of `tempfile` are:

```
123
<TAB><TAB>Hello How are you!
234
345
```

For more detail, try referring this [Sed tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/11/unix-sed-tutorial-append-insert-replace-and-count-file-lines/)