# Using sed to insert lines with escaped search pattern

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am follow the example of [using `sed` to insert lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739258/how-do-i-add-a-line-of-text-to-the-middle-of-a-file-using-bash) into a file at a specific pattern-match location. I have run the example from that question on my machine and it works perfectly.

So, for me, specifically, I am trying to insert the following:

```
<Location "someplace">
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Auth"
    AuthLDAPURL someurl
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on

    AuthLDAPBindDN someuser
    AuthLDAPBindPassword somepassword
</Location>
```

I want to insert it at the end of a .conf file ([this one to be exact](https://github.com/jdeathe/centos-ssh-apache-php/blob/master/var/www/app/vhost.conf)), specifically, immediately before the closing `</VirtualHost>`.

However, when I run

```
sed -n 'H;${x;s/\<\/VirtualHost> .*\n/test string &/;p;}' vhost.conf
```

to test, the contents of the file is printed but the file is not changed. Did I escape `</VirtualHost>` wrong or am I missing something else?

(I'm also open to other solutions for getting my content into the file.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in GNU Sed:

```
sed -i -n 'H;${x;s/<\/VirtualHost>.*/    test string\n&/;p;}' vhost.conf
```

For OSX/BSD:

```
sed -i '' -n 'H;${x;s/<\/VirtualHost>.*/    test string\'$'\n''&/;p;}' vhost.conf
```

Comment: So many things I need to learn from this (I'm using the BSD one). Thanks!

Comment: Quick follow up question: what's the best way to get my large multi-line content from above into this answer rather than `test string`? I can think of a few ways, but all are ugly.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
cat <<\! | sed -i '/<\/VirtualHost>/e cat /dev/stdin' file
test string
to be
inserted
!
```

Or perhaps more easily:

```
sed -i '/<\/VirtualHost>/i\
test string\
to be\
inserted' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the -i switch for in-place replace:

```
sed -i -n 'H;${x;s/\<\/VirtualHost> .*\n/test string &/;p;}' vhost.conf
```

Comment: After running that command I cannot find the string `test string` anywhere in the `vhost.conf` file - the same problem that I have above.

Comment: (Also, running either command apparently creates another file, `vhost.confn`, but as far as I can tell it is identical to `vhost.conf`)

Comment: It's sed -i -n  (not -in).  This works with GNU sed.  BSD sed requires that you specify a blank suffix like -i ''